# Can't start an electron-angular app after an angular update

Tags: angular, electron, angular8, webpack-4

I'm trying to build an electron app using angular, TypeORM, SQLite and other component as webpack.

I started my development from an example I found at GitHub: https://github.com/CubikNeRubik/angular-electron-typeorm-starter.

After a while, I decided to update angular from 8.0 to 8.2. Then it was impossible to start my application. I've got an error "ReferenceError: path is not defined".

I restarted from beginning with the 8.0 version of angular. Without changing anything, the app start normally.

I upgraded the project using the "npm update" command.

Then I got this error:

```
[error] ReferenceError: path is not defined
at Object.getBrowserConfig (/Volumes/Data/ProjetNodes/TestUpdate/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js:62:22)
at webpack_browser_config_1.generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext.wco (/Volumes/Data/ProjetNodes/TestUpdate/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/index.js:55:27)
at scriptTargets.map.scriptTarget (/Volumes/Data/ProjetNodes/TestUpdate/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:69:26)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at generateWebpackConfig (/Volumes/Data/ProjetNodes/TestUpdate/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:33:26)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Could someone explain my wrongdoing?

Here the modules version used before update:

```
"dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.800.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.8",
    "angular-cli-builders": "^2.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "commonjs": "0.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "electron": "^5.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.2",
    "electron-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "npx": "^10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "wait-on": "3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.34.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
}
```

The version after update:

```
"dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.22"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.4.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.25",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.25",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.12",
    "angular-cli-builders": "^2.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "commonjs": "0.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "electron": "^5.0.13",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "npx": "^10.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "wait-on": "3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To those whom encounter the same issue here is my tournaround.
I just add in the "node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js" file the code :

```
const path = require("path");
```

et Voilà.
h've a great day